# How can I draw an isometric Tiled-Map with python Arcade?

Tags: python, tiled, isometric, arcade

I'm trying to draw a isometric Tiled-Map with the python arcade library.
How can I project an isometric tiled-map grid onto the screen-space with arcade?

The following naive top-down 2d approach is not working:

```py
import arcade


class MyWindow(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self, width: int = 800, height: int = 600):
        super().__init__(width, height)

    def setup(self):
        self.tiled_map = arcade.load_tilemap("isometric_map1.json", 1)
        self.floor_list = self.tiled_map.sprite_lists["floor"]

    def on_draw(self):
        self.floor_list.draw()


def main():
    w = MyWindow()
    w.setup()
    arcade.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

output:
[image]

Comment: Can you share `isometric_map1.json` and the corresponding image?